# Arduino Pro Mini and GDEW0154T1 ePaper (e ink) display

Tags: display

I just got my Arduino Pro Mini and GDEW0154T1 ePaper display ([GDEW0154T1 display)](http://www.good-display.com/products_detail/&productId=305.html) and I'm trying to figure out a way to make them "talk". I started reading documentation and multiple sites but I still have no idea. I bought Breadboard, USB connector for Arduino and cables.

I think I need some port to connect display to Breadboard. Could you tell me where to look for it? What next?

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a special driver board.  Most of the drive circuitry is on the main chip built into the display, which is convenient, but it requires a number of capacitors (which are too big to fit into the display itself) on the various voltage pins, and a special power control circuit to ensure that the different voltages get enabled at the right time.

The datasheet details the capacitors that need connecting (Figure 7.5(2)), as well as the power control circuit (Figure 7.5(4)).

There is another small circuit snippet there as well (Figure 7.5(3), temperature sensor) but I haven't worked out the relevance of that yet.

Also you will need the right FPC connector, and a surface mount PCB to solder it on to, as well as the ability to solder it (reflow oven), so it's not a trivial task.  You may be able to find the right connector already soldered onto a breakout board if you look around - but make sure it *is* the right one, since there are many variations - number of pins, pitch of pins, upper or lower connection, etc.

Comment: Do you know what is component S11304BDL from Figure 7.5(4)? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @MattheW Any logic level N-channel MOSFET would do the job.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please help me once more? I recreated the circuit on the breadboard and I've got two doubts.
1. Do I connect 3.3V power to both VDDIO and VCI pins?
2. I look at both Figures 7-5 (2) and 7-5 (4) and I can see that VCI is on both of them. On none it is connected to 3.3V input. As far as I understand, it's connected to capacitor and ground on one side and to power control circuit on second side. Should I place 3.3V in between? Thank you for help!